# What causes context menus to close?

Tags: qt, qml

I have my simplified application window as the following. It opens a menu when clicked on it and while the menu is open, it is immediately closed when I click anywhere outside of it. I want to learn which specific event or signal causes context menus to close when clicked on their parent? I need to mimic this behavior manually.

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    MouseArea
    {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked:
         {
              contextMenu.popup()
         }
    }

    Menu
    {
        id: contextMenu

        MenuItem
        {
            text: "File"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end it all originates in a [QMouseEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html) I suppose.

Comment: I think it's something related to focus change !!!

Comment: `Menu` is derived from `Popup` which has [Popup.closePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#closePolicy-prop) property to define what cause to `Popup` to close. The default value is `Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside`. You can explore Popup [source code](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.11/src/quicktemplates2/qquickpopup.cpp) to get some specified info.